# How to create a Foursquare profile url from an ID?

Tags: api, foursquare

When I have a Foursquare user ID (retrieved via their API), how do I create a link to the user's profile on Foursquare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made the correct guess myself, use: `http://foursquare.com/u/:id` (eg. https://foursquare.com/u/26776). It will redirect to the actual profile url.

Comment: You saved me so much time.